GET http://127.0.0.1:5173/@vite/client net::ERR_CONNECTION REFUSED
i have an laravel application using inertia react and vite , i already deploy it using cloudflare tunnel , but if i open it using another device the error is appear and the css not applied , i think the css and js is not readable
but if i open from my laptop that used for development it worked normally
the error message from other device
the cloudflare tunnel configuration
vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel(['resources/css/app.css','resources/js/app.jsx']),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': '/resources/jsx',
        },
    },
    build: {
        outDir: 'public/build',
    },
    server: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 5173,
        https: false,
        cors: true,
    },
});

i tried to deploy laravel inertia using cloudflare tunnel , but i have some trouble the css and js is not readable so i expect to fixed it

127.0.0.1 is the localhost address that will not be reachable from another device as its specific to a device. You need to use either the network ip and have both the machines in the same network and then access the application or use some hosting service for the same.

@YashMaheshwari I see. I used an IPv4 address for the server host in the Vite config, and the problem is solved when the device is connected to the same Wi-Fi. However, how can I make it accessible from outside the same Wi-Fi network?

You need to have a service like ngrok that will create a url for you to access the app or use some hosting service.

*** Make sure you delete the hot file from the public directory, this may be creating the problem.
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {

    const isProduction = mode === 'production';

    plugins: [
        laravel(['resources/css/app.css','resources/js/app.jsx']),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': '/resources/jsx',
        },
    },
    build: {
        outDir: 'public/build',
    },
    server: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 5173,
        https: true,
        cors: true,
    },
});

